# jQuery text animate help. Stop at last word

Tags: text, jquery-animate

I found this code and it works great! But
how do I stop it when it reaches the last word?

```
(function(){

    // List your words here:
    var words = [
        'awesome',
        'incredible',
        'cool',
        'fantastic'
        ], i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn();
        });
       // 2 seconds
    }, 2000);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you start the code for the animation check if there is a word in the array and if not stop the interval.

```
(function(){

// List your words here:
var words = [
    'awesome',
    'incredible',
    'cool',
    'fantastic'
    ], i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(i+1 < words.length) {
        $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        window.clearIntervall(interval);
    }
   // 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

})();

clear interval can be found here:
http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/window.htm#clear_interval

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to interval by do this, It's will be continue adding word smoothly.

```
(function(){

// List your words here:
var words = [
    'awesome',
    'incredible',
    'cool',
    'fantastic'
    ], i = 0;

(function loop(){
    $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
        // send the loop function to fadeIn, It will exec when fadeIn complete
        $(this).html(words.shift()).fadeIn(loop);
    });
})();

})();
```

If you also need 2 sec delay, after each fadeIn effect completed. do this

```
(function(){

// List your words here:
var words = [
    'awesome',
    'incredible',
    'cool',
    'fantastic'
    ], i = 0;

(function loop(){
    $('#changerificwordspanid').fadeOut(function(){
        // settimeout for 2 sec before called loop
        $(this).html(words.shift()).fadeIn(function(){
           setTimeout(loop, 2000);
        });
    });
})();

})();
```